# HighCharts: Labels visible over tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, tooltip, label

Labels on my chart are showing over tooltip, which doesn't look very nice. I tried to play with `zIndex`, but to no result. How can I make tooltips not transparent? Here's my jsFiddle: http://www.jsfiddle.net/4scfH/3/

```js
$(function() {
  var chart;
  $(document).ready(function() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
      chart: {
        renderTo: 'graf1',
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false
      },

      title: {
        margin: 40,
        text: 'Podíl všech potřeb'
      },
      tooltip: {
        //pointFormat: '<b>{point.y} Kč [{point.percentage}%]</b>',
        percentageDecimals: 2,
        backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,1)",
        formatter: function() {
          return this.point.name + '<br />' + '<b>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y).replace(",", " ") + ' Kč [' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.percentage, 2) + '%]</b>';
        }
      },
      plotOptions: {
        pie: {
          allowPointSelect: true,
          cursor: 'pointer',
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: '#000000',
            connectorWidth: 2,
            useHTML: true,
            formatter: function() {
              return '<span style="color:' + this.point.color + '"><b>' + this.point.name + '</b></span>';
            }
          }
        }
      },
      series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Potřeba',
        data: [
          ['Firefox', 45.0],
          ['IE', 26.8], {
            name: 'Chrome',
            y: 12.8,
            sliced: true,
            selected: true
          },
          ['Safari', 8.5],
          ['Opera', 6.2],
          ['Others', 0.7]
        ]
      }]
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="graf1" style="width: 400px; height: 250px; float:left"></div>
```

Comment: Here is a very nice solution by tevfik6 https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/2528#issuecomment-283177513

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can set [`useHTML`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series<pie>.dataLabels.useHTML) and define your own tooltip via css:

http://jsfiddle.net/4scfH/4/

```js
tooltip: {
    borderWidth: 0,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0)",
    borderRadius: 0,
    shadow: false,
    useHTML: true,
    percentageDecimals: 2,
    formatter: function () {
        return '<div class="tooltip">' + this.point.name + '<br />' + '<b>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y).replace(",", " ") + ' Kč [' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.percentage, 2) + '%]</b></div>';
    }
},
```

CSS

```css
.label {
    z-index: 1 !important;
}

.highcharts-tooltip span {
    background-color: white;
    border:1 px solid green;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 9999 !important;
}

.tooltip {
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Explanation: when you set `useHTML` to true, it displays the tooltip text as HTML on the HTML layer, but still draws an SVG shape in the highcharts display SVG for the box and arrow. You would end up with data labels looking like they were drawn on top of the tooltip, but the tooltip text itself on top of the data labels. The config options above effectively hide the SVG tooltip shape and build and style the tooltip purely with HTML/CSS. The only down-side is that you lose the little "arrow" pointer.

Comment: This is what helped me: `.highcharts-tooltip span {
        z-index: 9999 !important;
    }`. Thanks so much!

Comment: @sebastian-bochan This solution is useful when you don't use a zooming option. Otherwise, the tooltip will cover the "Reset button". Is there an easy way to fix it?

Comment: @SebastianBochan Here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/ube5grw2/1/ Try to zoom a little and you will see that tooltip covers the "reset zoom" button.

Comment: Which browser do you use? Because I tested in Chrome and cannot observe that issues.

Comment: is it a bug?! and official site can not resolve it?!

Comment: The `useHTML` tricked me, as when you set it to true, it displays the tooltip text as HTML on the HTML layer, but draws an SVG shape in the highcharts display SVG. I had data labels looking like they were drawn on top of the tooltip, but the tooltip text itself was on top of the data label. The config options above effectively hide the SVG tooltip shape and I now build and style the tooltip purely with HTML/CSS.

Comment: you set backgroundColor in tooltip twice!

Answer (score 6):

If you set tooltip.backgroundColor to "rgba(255,255,255,1)" you'll get tooltip with "no transparency"

You will have to remove useHTML: true in the pie settings.

Fork of your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kairs/Z3UZ8/1/

```
tooltip: {
  backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,1)"
}
```

[Documentation on highchart](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.backgroundColor)

Comment: The problem is when use `dataLabels: { useHTML:true,`

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. The Labels were visible over the tooltip. Removing useHTML=true for the labels worked for me.

Comment: I had a similar situation as the questioner, but with a shared tooltip. Setting `useHTML: false` in the `legend` element, as @Sushil noted, did the trick exactly. It appeared that having `useHTML: true` set in both the legend *and* the tooltip caused undesirable quirks.

Comment: This does work for me (having the same issue), but unfortunately I *want* to use HTML on the labels for this series.

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue. My solution. 
Tooltip - useHTML = true. 
Tooltip - Formatter = HTML code there with one div container.
here margin in negative value is important in css.

```
tooltip: {
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,1)",
    useHTML: true,
    formatter: function() {
        var html = [];
        html.push('<b>Correlation to ' + this.point.p + '</b><br>');
        if (null != this.point.associatedPoints 
                && typeof this.point.associatedPoints != 'undefined' 
                && this.point.associatedPoints.length > 0) {
            $.each(this.point.associatedPoints, function(i, associatedPoint) {
                html.push('Responses: ' + associatedPoint.nFormatted);
            });
        }
        return '<div class="tooltip-body">' + html.join('') + '</div>';
    }
```

CSS:

```
.highcharts-tooltip span {
    z-index: 9999 !important;
    top:2px !important;
    left:2px !important;
}
.highcharts-tooltip span .tooltip-body{
    background-color:white;
    padding:6px; 
    z-index:9999 !important;
    margin-bottom:-14px;
    margin-right:-14px;
}
```

Comment: Welcome. Please explain how this answer adds to the currently selected one, and the other already existing.

Answer (score 2):

set tooltip outside property to true.
`outside : true`

Comment: this should be the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

and if you dont want to daddle in the problems there are in useHTML, here is the way to do it in the svg:

```
 Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.Chart.prototype, 'redraw', function(proceed, animation) {
  proceed.call(this, animation);
  try {
   if (this.legend.options.floating) {
    var z = this.legend.group.element, zzz = z.parentNode;
    zzz.removeChild(z);
    zzz.appendChild(z); //zindex in svg is determined by element order
   }
  } catch(e) {

  } 
 });
```

Comment: please provide jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

For Highchart tooltips with html format

Highchart config

```
tooltip: {
    borderWidth: 0,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0)",
    shadow: false,
    useHTML: true
    ........
},
```

CSS:

```
.highcharts-tooltip>span {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #172F8F;
    border-radius: 5px;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 9999!important;
    padding: .8em;
    left: 0!important;
    top: 0!important;
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I still had issues with some of the solutions around, setting z-index: 999 on .tooltip wasn't having any effect because of the various container divs. But, I've found setting this works nicely (when legend and tooltip are HTML). No need for setting other z-indexes either:

`.highcharts-legend {
    z-index: -1;
}`