# Highcharts - tooltip / yaxis zindex issue

Tags: highcharts

The issue I am having is that the tooltip on my line graph for the first few points is behind the values on the Y-Axis.  I assume this is just a z-index issue between the tooltips and yaxis.

I wasnt sure the correct way to fix this issue, if there was some option I should use or is this something that needs to be addressed CSS.

This issue did not start happening until I changed the yaxis to use HTML. Maybe is it caused by my formatting?

```
yAxis: {
    labels: {
useHTML:true,   
formatter: function() {
    var amount = this.value;

    if(this.value > 0 ){
        return  '<span class="format_positive">'  + amount + '</span>';
    } else {
        return  '<span class="format_negative">' + '(' + amount + ')' + '</span>'
    }

    }},
    alternateGridColor: '#F5F5F5',
    minorTickInterval: 'auto',
    lineWidth: 1,
    tickWidth: 1,
    title:{ text: 'Total Amounts'}
    }
```

Comment: Could you share your code i.e in jsfiddle.net? Because default examples has no that issue.

Comment: I'll work on creating one. But I should mention that it did not start behaving this way until I changed the useHTML to true on my y-axis. I can update my original question with the details.

Comment: I created a small sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/JEaPZ/

Comment: Seems similar to this topic:
only he wasnt using html for labels so this solution didnt work for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130311/highcharts-labels-visible-over-tooltip

Comment: Which browser do you use?

Comment: happens in chrome and firefox for sure and when it renders on mobile

Comment: Well I cannot reproduce it, but have you tried my solution from related thread, which you posted?