# Tooltip issue on columnrange

Tags: highcharts

Please look at the example. I've created on jsfiidle.
http://jsfiddle.net/cr1t/LdLn2/1/

The issue I'm having is with the tooltip that floats above the graph. The text on the column range seems to have a much higher z-index. But no matter what I try and set it on the div style sheet, it shows threw.  I'd like the have the point detail in html, because I want to make it a hyperlink tag.

```
plotOptions: {
        columnrange: {

                dataLabels: {
                    inside: true,
                    enabled: true,
                    useHTML: true,

                    formatter: function () {
                        if (this.y === this.point.low) {
                    return '<div style="padding:2px;text-align:center;color:black;overflow:hidden;width:' + (this.point.plotLow - this.point.plotHigh - 4) + 'px">' +      this.point.low + '°C - ' + this.point.high + '°C </div>';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    },
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [HighCharts: Labels visible over tooltip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130311/highcharts-labels-visible-over-tooltip)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Anto

I followed the duplicate.

I managed to get it working the way I wanted with css

http://jsfiddle.net/cr1t/LdLn2/2/

```
.highcharts-data-labels {
    z-index: 1 !important;
}

.highcharts-tooltip span {
    background-color:white;
    opacity:1;
    z-index:9999 !important;
    padding:5px
}

.tooltip {
    padding:5px
}
```

and setting the style on the tooltip

```
tooltip: {
                backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,1)",
                 style: {

                    padding: '1px'
                },
                shadow: false,
                useHTML: true,
                percentageDecimals: 2,
                formatter: function () {
                    return '<div class="tooltop">'+ this.point.category + '<br />'  +
                        'Temprature ' + this.point.low + '°C - ' + this.point.high + '°C </div>'
                }

        }
```