# Is it possible to avoid tooltip text from going behind title?

Tags: highcharts

In one of my Highcharts, there is a large tooltip text, on mouseover, half of the text goes behind the title of the highchart.
Is there any way to avoid this ?

Comment: Would you be able to attach a screenshot? I know what's wrong but I need to see it to confirm

Comment: similar question answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130311/highcharts-labels-visible-over-tooltip

Comment: Could you recreate your example as live demo ?

Comment: The issue got resolved by  referring this- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130311/highcharts-labels-visible-over-tooltip