# Highcharts tooltip overlap with next chart

Tags: highcharts

I am having a weird issue, where the tooltip for the chart is overlapping with the next chart and clipping off. Is there a way i could display a long tooltip ? These each chart are inside the `col-lg-3` class used in the Twitter bootstap framework.

JsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/12kwyftq/8/

Two things i need solution for

1. I need the tooltip to show completely without clipping
2. I also need the tooltip to display on whole chart and not when i hover over       the green bar (outer radius)

[image: Tooltip Description]

Comment: could you add your code on fiddle

Comment: similar question answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130311/highcharts-labels-visible-over-tooltip

Comment: @NishithChaturvedi I will try this out and let you know in comments by monday. If this works you might need to include same as answer so i can accept

Comment: ok , but it would be better if you can add your code here or on fiddle.

Comment: @NishithChaturvedi added jsFiddle , let me know if you need anything more

Comment: @NishithChaturvedi another fiddle to display the issue http://jsfiddle.net/b9gBN/1/ from here https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1574