# Display image inside tspan tag of highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, highcharts

I'm using [highcharts](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.area.dataLabels.format) library to display pie chart, I'm trying to display image/icon before the text of labels on chart.
I tried to add it using ways of display images in svg but it didn't work. because highcharts added my image inside onclick action on label.

```
format: '<image width="40" height="40" xlink:href="{point.img}" /> <span><defs>'
  +'<pattern id="{point.name}" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100" height="100">'
    +'<image xlink:href="{point.img}" x="0" y="0" width="30" height="30" />'
  +'</pattern>'
+'</defs></span> {point.name} <span style="fill:url(#{point.name}); stroke: red; stroke-width:2px;"></span>: {point.percentage:.1f} %'
```

I tried two ways one with `<image/>` tag and another with `<defs>` and `<pattern>` tags

I want to display images, how can I do that? is it possible ? here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jc45j7Ln/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use html tags with `dataLabels.useHTML` flag set to true, see:

```
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                useHTML: true,
                format: '<img width="40" height="40" src="{point.options.img}" /> <span> {point.name} <span style="fill:url(#{point.name}); stroke: red; stroke-width:2px;"></span>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                style: {
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jc45j7Ln/2/

**Note**: Since labels are rendered in HTML, then SVG's tooltip will be rendered under HTML. In that case see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130311/highcharts-labels-visible-over-tooltip).