# Highcharts - StackLabels displayed over tooltip when useHTML=true

Tags: highcharts

StackLabels are displayed over tooltip, when `useHTML` is set to true in `stackLabels`.

This looks quite odd.

I tried adjusting z-index of `.highcharts-stack-labels` and `.highcharts-tooltip`, but no luck.

P.S - I tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130311/highcharts-labels-visible-over-tooltip), but that didn't work for me.

**Fiddle** : https://jsfiddle.net/nrcuks2a/

Answer (score 1):

The below option solved the problem

```
tooltip: {
    outside: true
}
```

see [here](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.outside)

updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/nrcuks2a/2/